# Ship collision function in Battleship (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, collision

I've been making a game of battleships in Javascript that puts 3 random ships that are 3 blocks of length either horizontally/vertically on the map.

This is how I create the field and place 1 ship on it

```
function Ship (size, direction) {
    this.coveredFields = [];
   this.place = function (sizeY, sizeX) { // sizeX & sizeY: size of fields in both dimensions

       // pick randomly within our limits
       var locationX;
       var locationY;
       if (direction) {
        locationX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeX - 1 - size));
        locationY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeY - 1));
       } else {
        locationX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeX - 1));
        locationY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizeY - 1 - size));
       }

       // setting locations
       for (var i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        if (direction) {
            this.coveredFields.push(locationY * 10 + locationX + i)
        } else {
            this.coveredFields.push((locationY + i) * 10 + locationX)
        }
       }
   }
}

var ship1 = new Ship(3, true);
ship1.place(7,7);
ship1.coveredFields;
```

I then put the ships in an empty array

```
var shipsArray = [];
shipsArray.push(ship1.coveredFields
```

The only problem with my game is that sometimes my ships overlap each other on when they are put randomly somehwere on the field and I don't want that to happen. I've been trying to make a collision function like this:

```
  function collision(direction)
{
for (var i = 0; i < shipsArray.length; i++) 
{
    for (var j = 0; j < direction.length; j++) 
    {
        if (shipsArray[i].direction.indexOf(direction[j]) != -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

At the moment this function does not return any errors, but it doesn't give me any solution either since the ships sometime still collide.

Would there be any smarter way to detect collision between ships than the function above, or how could I improve on it ?

If you need more code I'll edit my answer, but I hope I am being thorough enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build a `Map` and place the ships onto it:

```
function Ship(size, direction) {
  // Keep Ship simple
  this.size = null;
  this.direction = null;
  this.coveredFields = null;
};

function BattleMap(boundaries) {
  this.ships = [];
  this.boundaries = boundaries;
};

BattleMap.prototype = {
  createShipAtRandomPos: function() {
    var ship = new Ship();
    // check for collision here and set size+direction
    this.ships.push(ship);
    return ship;
  }
};

var map = new BattleMap();
var ship1 = map.createShipAtRandomPos();
```